# Ubuntu 22.04 "Bricked"

Tags: sudo

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04, and after compiling an NXP Driver for another piece of hardware am no longer able to run almost all commands. Anything containing "sudo" or "ls" returns the following and does not execute:

```
aarch64-binfmt-P: Could not open '/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1': No such file or directory
```

I manually restarted the system and get the same error. Is this machine essentially bricked? I can't use sudo to install any patches so seem to be stuck.

Notes from the comments:

```
$ echo $PATH 
/home/cwade/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
$
$
$ type sudo
sudo is /home/cwade/bin/sudo
```

`/bin/ls` works. It returns all the files at `/home/user`.

Comment: Is your machine ARM based? ... Have you changed the binaries for those two commands/overwritten them ... What's the output of e.g. `file /usr/bin/ls /bin/sudo`?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! It's an Intel x86 machine, that command returns the same "aarch64 etc..."

Comment: Check your PATH, your commands seem to be picking up your cross toolpath binaries.

Comment: Ok, echo $PATH returns /home/cwade/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

Comment: Are there  ARM binaries  of `ls` and `sudo` early in your path ... check which binaries get called with `type ls sudo` ... Also please check your kernel `uname -a`

Comment: uname -a returns the same "aarch64......", type ls sudo returns sudo is /home/cwade/bin/sudo. Also, how are you getting cmd phrases to show up highlighted in your comment?

Comment: What does `/bin/ls` returne? Does it work?

Comment: Text looks like `this` when it's put between two backticks `\`...\`` ... :)

Comment: Ah ok thanks @Raffa! `/bin/ls` works; returns all the files at `home\user`. Seems like placing `/bin` before any command works

Comment: It's your path ... @ubfan1 perfect guess, please make it an answer ... Meanwhile, running `PATH="/bin:${PATH}"` will temporarily fix those making `ls`, `sudo` ... etc. run correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your PATH is normal, but somehow your cross compilation tools got put into your ${HOME}/bin, which is normally pretty early in the PATH.  A normal setup is to isolate those cross tools in their own location (I prefer that way rather than dumping them, albeit with their full names to avoid confusion into system areas).  Below is a sample of a setup for defining some environment variables for a cross development.

```
MY_ARM_BASE=${HOME}/dev/toolchain/arm-2008q3
C_INCLUDE_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/include:${MY_ARM_BASE}/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/include-fixed
LIBRARY_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/lib:${MY_ARM_BASE}/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.3.2
#OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH
COMPILER_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/bin
#LD_RUN_PATH
#GPROF_PATH
#######
CC=${COMPILER_PATH}/gcc
CXX=${COMPILER_PATH}/g++
RANLIB=${COMPILER_PATH}/ranlib
STRIP=${COMPILER_PATH}/strip
export C_INCLUDE_PATH LIBRARY_PATH CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH COMPILER_PATH
export CC CXX RANLIB STRIP
```